# How to create nested lists in Pyspark using collect_list over a window?

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DF I aggregated using `collect_list` and `PartitionBy` to pull lists of values associated with a grouped set of columns. As a result, for the grouped columns, I now have a new column containing a list of the elements associated with group. However, I would like this list to be further broken down so it contains nested lists. It's also important that the order of these columns is sorted by Date. See below:

```
data = [
    ["ABC", 1, 3, "2020-04-01", "product_one"],
    ["ABC", 1, 3, "2020-04-01", "product_two"],
    ["ABC", 1, 3, "2020-04-12", "product_one"],
    ["ABC", 1, 3, "2020-04-12", "product_two"],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ID", "Ref_No", "Number", "Date", "Product"])
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

w = Window.partitionBy("ID", "Ref_No", "Number").orderBy("Date")

grouped_sdf = (
    sdf.withColumn(
        "Products",
        spark_fns.collect_list("Product").over(w),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "Dates",
        spark_fns.collect_set("Date").over(w),
    )
    .groupby("ID", "Ref_No", "Number")
    .agg(
        spark_fns.max("Products").alias("Products"),
        spark_fns.max("Dates").alias("Dates"),
    )
)
```

```
ID  Ref_No Number Products         Dates
ABC   1      3    [product_one,   [2020-04-01,
                   product_two,    2020-04-12]
                   product_one,    
                   product_two]
```

I would like the lists in the column `Products` to actually contain lists as well, associated with each timing. So the desired output is:

So we know that the first list (within the list) is associated with the first date, and then second list within the list is associated with the second.

```
ID  Ref_No Number Products         Dates
ABC   1      3    [[product_one,   [2020-04-01,
                   product_two],    2020-04-12]
                   [product_one,    
                   product_two]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do two group by and collect_list:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = sdf.groupBy(sdf.columns[:4]).agg(
    F.collect_list('Product').alias('Product')
).groupBy(sdf.columns[:3]).agg(
    F.expr('transform(sort_array(collect_list(struct(Date, Product))), x -> x.Product) as Product'), 
    F.sort_array(F.collect_list('Date')).alias('Date')
)

result.show(20,0)
+---+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
|ID |Ref_No|Number|Product                                                 |Date                    |
+---+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
|ABC|1     |3     |[[product_one, product_two], [product_one, product_two]]|[2020-04-01, 2020-04-12]|
+---+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: this works really well, the only thing is it doesn't retain the dates ordered.

Comment: Could you try using `F.sort_array(F.collect_list('Date')).alias('Date')` ?

Comment: yes definitely... the only thing is (and this is why I was hung up on the window function) is I need the other columns to also be sorted by date haha. the sort_array works really nicely though.